# What is the coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I am basic user of GIS. I have a project in Rwanda and have received CAD information in a coordinate system I am unaware of. In addition this isn't the first time I have come across similar references for similar areas. Can anyone work out the coordinate system from these coordinates:

- decimal degrees `-2.2710, 30.2612`
- unknown system `529041.54, 4748727.20`

Comment: Probably the decimal degree are in WGS84, you can try to insert into google earth and check if they are in the right position.

Answer (score 5):

I think I've found the coordinate system you're looking for. 
Your unknown coordinate reference system seems to be referred to in Rwanda as ITRF 2005 / TM Rwanda. It is a projected coordinate system using Transverse Mercator with the following parameters :

```
False Easting : 500,000
False Northing : 5,000,000
Central meridian : 30
Latitude of origin : 0
Scale factor : 0.9999
Linear unit : Meter
Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_ITRF_2005
Datum: D_ITRF_2005
```

The crs is mentioned in some ESRI Rwanda documents such as [this one](https://www.esri.rw/~/media/esri-germany-group/esri-rw/files/How_to_solve_the_data_shift_problem_in_Rwandan_Projections.pdf) and is used by local government in some web services. The ESRI-style WKT for that crs is:

```
PROJCS["ITRF_2005",GEOGCS["GCS_ITRF_2005",DATUM["D_ITRF_2005",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",5000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",30.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

And the proj4 string would be:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=30 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=5000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

(Note: I did not use any transformation between ITRF2005 and WGS84)

With these assumptions, in decimal degrees, your example unknown point is located at lat,lon: -2.2726260, 30.2611137:

[image]